# How to use tool 'vegeta' in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, vegeta

I installed golang latest version (go version go1.17.1 windows/amd64)

And I successfully installed vegeta with command `go install github.com/tsenart/vegeta@latest`

But if I command, as I saw in `vegeta --help`, `echo "GET http://localhost:8080/" | vegeta attack -duration=5s | tee results.bin | vegeta report` in cmd

then I face
`'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.`

I don't know why this happens

Did I command something wrong? I think that `echo "GET ~~ vegeta report` command is for Unix-like, maybe not for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tee` is (broadly-speaking) a Linux command. Luckily, [powershell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/docs/learning-powershell) has a version, try using it instead of `cmd`.

[Related question](/questions/796476)